# dependencies Needed by a mvn plugin are not resolved

Tags: maven, plugins, dependencies

I have created a Maven plugin called foo that needs a JAR file say xyz.jar in order to compile and run. In the pom file of plugin project foo I have provided xyz.jar with provided scope in the dependencies section. I do not want to package the xyz.jar file in the plugin.

The plugin foo will be triggered by another project say bar in its install phase. So I added the plugin foo in the `<build><plugins><plugin>...</plugin></plugins></build>` section of the project bar. Project bar has the dependency of xyz.jar in its `<dependencies>` section. When I run install goal the classes present in the xyz.jar and which are referred by the plugin foo throw `ClassNotFoundException` at runtime.

How can I resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

Every plugin and the Maven Project have separated classloaders, that's why it is not working. In general a plugin shouldn't depend on a dependency of the project. So remove the provided scope will solve it. Manipulating the classloader is very tricky.

> I do not want to package the xyz.jar file in the plugin.

Well, it is not. It is just a reference.

I can't tell what your plugin is doing. I suggest to have a look at the plugins from Apache Maven or Codehaus Mojo to see how it is done.

Answer (score 0):

Project and plugin dependencies are separated in Maven. If your plugin requires some external `jars` you need to provide them in `<dependencies>` section located **in the plugin tag** (not together with your project dependencies). For example:

```
<build>
   <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>...</groupId>
        <artifactId>yourPluginArtifactId</artifactId>
        <version>...</version>
        <dependencies>
          <dependency>
            <groupId>...</groupId>
            <artifactId>xyz</artifactId>
            <version>...</version>
          </dependency>
        </dependencies>
      </plugin>
   </plugins>
</build>
```